# If I have multiple values in a single cell in Excel, is it possible to filter by those values in a pivot table?

Tags: excel, filter, pivot

So I have the following table:

```
Name        Budget     State(s)
Project A   $100,000    Maryland
Project B   $200,000    Virginia
Project C   $150,000    Virginia, Maryland
Project D   $175,000    DC, Virginia
Project E   $50,000     DC
```

I want to build a pivot table that will allow me to determine the total budget of all projects in a specific state (i.e., to answer a question like "how much money is being spent on projects that conduct at least some of their operations in Maryland?").  Would it be possible to sort the above data by State in a pivot table if some projects occur across state lines (i.e., have multiple values in the State column)? If this is not possible, is there some sort of workaround or alternative method that could accomplish the same goal? I would like to avoid having multiple State columns (this is a simplified version of the problem I am encountering - my actual data has 50+ location options, so having multiple columns, each with a single entry, would not be practical).

Comment: Don't really 100% understand your problem. If you want to split text, you can use **Text to Columns** under Data Tab

Answer (score 1):

You can use sumif as shown below -

[image]